# adding data frame of counts to template data frame in R

Tags: r, plyr

I have data.frames of counts such as:

```
a <- data.frame(id=1:10,
                "1"=c(rep(1,3),rep(0,7)),
                "3"=c(rep(0,4),rep(1,6)))
names(a)[2:3] <- c("1","3")
a
> a
   id 1 3
1   1 1 0
2   2 1 0
3   3 1 0
4   4 0 0
5   5 0 1
6   6 0 1
7   7 0 1
8   8 0 1
9   9 0 1
10 10 0 1
```

and a template data.frame such as

```
m <- data.frame(id=1:10,
                "1"= rep(0,10),
                "2"= rep(0,10),
                "3"= rep(0,10),
                "4"= rep(0,10))
names(m)[-1] <- 1:4
m
> m
   id 1 2 3 4
1   1 0 0 0 0
2   2 0 0 0 0
3   3 0 0 0 0
4   4 0 0 0 0
5   5 0 0 0 0
6   6 0 0 0 0
7   7 0 0 0 0
8   8 0 0 0 0
9   9 0 0 0 0
10 10 0 0 0 0
```

and I want to add the values of a into the template m
in the appropraite columns, leaving the rest as 0.

This is working but I would like to know
if there is a more elegant way, perhaps using plyr or data.table:

```
provi <- rbind.fill(a,m)
provi[is.na(provi)] <- 0
mnew <- aggregate(provi[,-1],by=list(provi$id),FUN=sum)
names(mnew)[1] <- "id"
mnew <- mnew[c(1,order(names(mnew)[-1])+1)]
mnew
> mnew
   id 1 2 3 4
1   1 1 0 0 0
2   2 1 0 0 0
3   3 1 0 0 0
4   4 0 0 0 0
5   5 0 0 1 0
6   6 0 0 1 0
7   7 0 0 1 0
8   8 0 0 1 0
9   9 0 0 1 0
10 10 0 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the concise option would be:

```
m[names(a)] <- a
```

Or we `match` the column names ('i1'), use that to create the column index with `max.col`, `cbind` with the row index ('i2'), and a similar step can be done to create 'i3'.  We change the values in 'm' corresponding to 'i2' with the 'a' values based on 'i3'.

```
i1 <- match(names(a)[-1], names(m)[-1])
i2 <-  cbind(m$id, i1[max.col(a[-1], 'first')]+1L)
i3 <- cbind(a$id, max.col(a[-1], 'first')+1L)
m[i2] <- a[i3]
m
#   id 1 2 3 4
#1   1 1 0 0 0
#2   2 1 0 0 0
#3   3 1 0 0 0
#4   4 0 0 0 0
#5   5 0 0 1 0
#6   6 0 0 1 0
#7   7 0 0 1 0
#8   8 0 0 1 0
#9   9 0 0 1 0
#10 10 0 0 1 0
```

---

A `data.table` option would be `melt/dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(a), id.var='id')[,
     variable:= factor(variable, levels=1:4)], 
     id~variable, value.var='value', drop=FALSE, fill=0)
#    id 1 2 3 4
# 1:  1 1 0 0 0
# 2:  2 1 0 0 0
# 3:  3 1 0 0 0
# 4:  4 0 0 0 0
# 5:  5 0 0 1 0
# 6:  6 0 0 1 0
# 7:  7 0 0 1 0
# 8:  8 0 0 1 0
# 9:  9 0 0 1 0
#10: 10 0 0 1 0
```

---

A similar `dplyr/tidyr` option would be

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(a, Var, Val, -id) %>%
     mutate(Var=factor(Var, levels=1:4)) %>% 
     spread(Var, Val, drop=FALSE, fill=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `merge`, too:

```
res <- suppressWarnings(merge(a, m, by="id", suffixes = c("", ""))) 
(res[, which(!duplicated(names(res)))][, names(m)])
#    id 1 2 3 4
# 1   1 1 0 0 0
# 2   2 1 0 0 0
# 3   3 1 0 0 0
# 4   4 0 0 0 0
# 5   5 0 0 1 0
# 6   6 0 0 1 0
# 7   7 0 0 1 0
# 8   8 0 0 1 0
# 9   9 0 0 1 0
# 10 10 0 0 1 0
```